# How to turn Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop into a Wireless access point?

Tags: 14.04, wireless-access-point

when I trying to host internet in my Ubuntu 14.04 it's not showing Option buttons in wireless tab...[like shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgVQz.png)

So help me to create a Wifi hotspot ... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the network page in the Wireless section, you should see an option like 'Use as Hotspot' below. Like this.

[image: Wireless Options Menu in System Settings]

Do you see that?

Comment: Yeah @navjotsingh I can see that...what's process after that...just clicking Use as Hotspot does create my laptop as  Wifi router ?  just asking